# How to create a dropdown image in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, dropdown

How do I create a dropdown image in WPF?

I want to have an image on my xaml window (without arrow or anything else, just an image).
When I click the image a dropdown should appear.
On the dropdown I can select an item.
When the dropdown opens the current selected item should be checked.

I tried this on an image, on a dropdown, but cannot find how to make it work...
Thank you very much!

Comment: What did you try

Comment: I used google to find solutions but dit not find a good one. Now i have the following code:
<fa:ImageAwesome.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu >
      <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Menu 1"/>
     </ContextMenu>
    </fa:ImageAwesome.ContextMenu>

This is working but I want to bind the menuItems to a List or Dictionary in my viewmodel

Comment: what happens when you bind the ItemSource?

Comment: can you give me an example how to do this? with the xaml and codebeside?